# how can i find IDLE in my mac though i installed my python3 with pip?

Tags: python, pip, python-idle

I entered '''idle''' on terminal

and it only shows me python2 that has already been here.

How can i see python3 idle on my mac

while i installed python3 with pip?

Answer (score 0):

you can specify the version
idle3

Comment: How about use `which python3` to find the location, and I think there must be IDLE3 in the folder.